# RAID 10 Configured in Smart Array Administrator but after install centos 7 show all disks

Tags: linux, centos7, hp, raid10

I have an HP ProLiant DL320e Gen8 with 4 disks. I have configured the disks as a single RAID10 array in the HP Smart Array Administrator. After configuring Smart Array Administrator I can see 1 logical drive with mirroring everything looks OK. But after this configuration I want to install centos 7 but when I get to the disk selection part of the install I see 4 separate disks, not the logical disk.

How do I solve this?

My controller version HP Smart Array B120i RAID Controller (v3.54.0)

I tried configure RAID10 in centos but after the installation finished I cannot start the system and I see this error:

```
Non-system disks or disk error replace and strike any key when ready
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HP Smart Array B120i RAID Controller is what some people refer to as '[fake raid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Firmware-_and_driver-based)'. It is an HBA that relies on Windows drivers to provide software raid. From the manufacturer's datasheet:

*HP Dynamic Smart Array is a RAID solution combining a storage host bus adapter (HBA) and proprietary software components.Eliminating most of the hardware RAID controller components and relocating advanced RAID algorithms from a hardware-basedcontroller into device driver software lowers the total solution cost*

This why you are seeing four separate drives during the Centos install.

There are some drivers available for Redhat/Centos [here](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5293150&swItemId=MTX_d13cacff65354a249da627e2d5&swEnvOid=4184) but I don't know if these are the latest or what the exact install procedure is.

[Datasheet reference](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/575234/Hp-B120i.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I install drivers on the centos installer step?